# Fade background images without HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fade

I am trying to make background images fade in fade out. I can't change HTML code.

```
        <ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;">
          <li class="slide-0 activeslide">
           <a target="_blank">
           <img src="image1" style="width: 994px; height: 745.5px; left: 0px; top: -39.5px;">
         </a></li></ul>
```

There is a plugin for making the image looks nice on every screen. So I have to use just a Javascript. and I get here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var parent = document.getElementById('supersized'); // because img has no ID
        var element = parent.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos > 710) {
            $(element).attr("src", 'image1');
        } else {
            $(element).attr("src", 'image2');
        }
    });
});
```

Then I realised that in this case I cannot make Fade. So I came with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        var parent = document.getElementById('supersized');
        var element = parent.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        if (scroll_pos > 710) {
            $(element).attr("src", 'img1').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(element).attr("src", 'img1').fadeOut();
        };
        if (scroll_pos < 710) {
            $(element).attr("src", 'img2').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(element).attr("src", 'img2').fadeOut();
        };

    });
});
```

But this doesn't work. 
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: 1. Show HTML. 2. Why using jQuery mixed with pure JS (`document.getElementById('supersized')` => `$('#supersized')`)?

Comment: 1.:   ` <ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;"><li class="slide-0 activeslide"><a target="_blank"><img src="image1" style="width: 994px; height: 745.5px; left: 0px; top: -39.5px;"></a></li></ul>`

2. It has no reason, was just a mistake

Comment: Edit question with your HTML formatted

Answer (score 1):

```
**HTML AND CSS**

<style>    
#effect {
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: #555 url("/sites/default/files/fashion-and-jewellery.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
   }    

#effect {
  max-width: 490px;
  height: 320px;
  }  
</style>

<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>


**JQUERY**

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#effect").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, "slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. He can't change HTML, 2. Comment why your answer is working, what issues does it fix and any pit-falls